# How to change the data that appear on the axis using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am having problems on setting the data that appear on the xAxis. At this momment I am using the Time in seconds, at this point everything is correct and the data is set aright but in the xAxis I would like to have the time in minutes from the first one, instead of the seconds on I calculate the position. I am wondering if it is posible or I have to re-do the xScale.

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
              .domain([
                d3.min(ds, function(d, i){ return d.Seconds - 100;}),
                d3.max(ds, function(d){ return d.Seconds})     
              ])
              .range([
                w - padding,
                padding + 100,
              ]);
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([
              1 ,
              d3.max(ds, function(d){ return d.Place + 2; })
            ])
            .range([ padding, h - padding ]);
```

Another question I have is that now, I set a function that makes the name and the dots appear bigger on mouseover, Is it possible to make it both at the same time? this is the piece of code on I have it set, but as I did the dots and the labels separetly I cannot see how to connect them.

```
var dots = svg.selectAll("circle")
.data(ds)
.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr({
  cx: function(d, i){ return xScale(d.Seconds); },
  cy: function(d){ return yScale(d.Place); },
  r: 5,
  fill: function(d) { return doping(d.Doping);}
})
.on("mouseover", function(d){
d3.select(this).attr({
  r: 7
});
})
.on("mouseout", function(d){
d3.select(this).attr({
  r: 5
})
});

/* - - - Labeling the chart - - - */
var labels = svg.selectAll(".label")
  .data(ds)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
.text(function(d){ return d.Name; })
.attr({
x: function(d){ return xScale(d.Seconds) + 20; },
y: function(d){ return yScale(d.Place)+5;},
"class": "label",
"font-size": "10px",
"font-family": "sans-serif",
"text-anchor": "start",
"fill": "#666666"
})
.on("mouseover", function(d){
d3.select(this).attr({
"font-size": "14px"

});
})
.on("mouseout", function(d){
d3.select(this).attr({
  "font-size": "10px"
})
})
}
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/DiazPedroAbel/pen/xEgNrR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways for achieving the effect that you ask in your second question (*"I set a function that makes the name and the dots appear bigger on mouseover, Is it possible to make it both at the same time?"*), such as using groups. I particularly like a different approach, using classes to select all elements I want at once:

First, we set the same class for the circles and the texts:

```
class: function(d, i){ return (d.Name).split(" ").join("") + i}
```

Then, inside the `mouseover`, we retrieve the class:

```
var thisClass = d3.select(this).attr("class");
```

And use it for changing both circles and texts.

For your first question, if I understand it correctly (maybe not), you are already showing the time in seconds. So, all you need is to divide it by 60:

```
var xAxisGen = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(8)
    .tickFormat(function(d){ return d/60});
```

Here is your codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpvxxb?editors=1010

Comment: Thnaks a lot Gerardo, I was facing some problems setting on the xAxis the differnce in time between one rider and the other but finally I did it. I just need to make it responsive. Here is the link in case you want to see it finished :)
[link](http://codepen.io/DiazPedroAbel/pen/xEgNrR)

Comment: It seems good! Btw, you know that you can style the axis path in the CSS, don't you?

Comment: I was looking for different ways to style the axis, but all I find was through Blocks examples. Need to go deeper on this.

Also Gerardo, something funny happens. Now I set two more svg circles to tell the user why some circles are red and others white, but when I add those two circles to this area of the svg, another 2 disappear from the riders. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without even seeing your code: you are selecting existing circles. Your enter selection *cannot* select existing elements. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/d3.js/2135/selections/16948/the-role-of-placeholders-in-enter-selections#t=201609270855017139283

Comment: But, of course, this is a wild guess. Share this new code with the 2 circles and I'll have a look later.

Comment: Yes sure, here is the link [codepen]http://codepen.io/DiazPedroAbel/pen/xEgNrR

But I am pretty sure that as you did is because I am moving those elements, I am going to check the link you provide to see if I can fix it.

Comment: I fixed that problem with the link provided. If someone needs to see the result in the link provided in the last comment you can find it. Thank you very much Gerardo.

Comment: Good to see that! But please, keep in mind that this method (selecting something that doesn't exist and never will exist) only works and makes sense if you **don't have** an update and exit selections (that is, if you don't update your chart based on data).

Comment: so if this data that I am adding from an API changes, an now instead of 13 elements has 14? I will not get this new element? How could I fix that problem in a non static enviroment, I mean when data can change in the future.

Comment: Just set a class to your circles in the enter selection and use that class in the update and exit selections. This avoids selecting those 2 circles for the legends.